# Ajax call when click on Browser refresh Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, page-refresh

Im struggling with Ajax Deep linking and wonder if is possible to make an Ajax call when user click on Browser refresh button.

I tried to use `beforeunload` It works but still make a request to the server after the ajax call Is there a way to prevent the request to the server ?

```
    $(window).on('beforeunload',function(e){
        //ajax call here.          
    });
```

Comment: What is the real problem here. Sounds like a poor bandaid solution.

Comment: You can not prevent the page from leaving.

Comment: The problem is I cannot figure how to use HTML5 History API to use it without the hash tag. I have posted a question about it couple of days ago but no answer. I want clean urls without hash in an Ajax app. Could you help ?

Comment: Link to his question above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023850/html5-history-api-browser-refresh

Comment: @degenerate That is my question and nobody answer it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hook into knowing when a user clicks refresh. From a browser perspective they are simply navigating away from the page. You could hook into the onbeforeunload method to do something...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return 'Testing...' }
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Is there a way to prevent the request to the server after the Ajax Call.